# Creating nice tables with Rmarkdown using powerpoint_presentation

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

I used to create nice tabels in HTML format using `knitr::kable` and `library(kableExtra)`, but I can't seem to find the right solution when output is  a powerpoint (`output: powerpoint_presentation` in YAML header). Can one use LaTeX with powerpoint?

What should to make my output look professional? For example the table bellow.

```
summary(cars)
```

EDIT: I have found the `flextable` package and it seems to work. If you have a better solution or tips your are welcome to answer the question.